# How can I add a .dtd validation to an .xml file created by a .xq Query?

Tags: xquery

So my query was working fine and I now need to verify the resulting .xml with a .dtd validation. My .xq looked like this before:

> < root>
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> < /root>

Now it looks like this:

> < !DOCTYPE root SYSTEM 'validation.dtd'>
>
> < root>
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> < /root>

Running the .xq now, however, throws the following error:

> XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #...as xs:integer external; < !D#:
>
> Expected '--' or '[CDATA[' after '< !'
>
> Static error(s) in query

I don't know what this error means, and I'm unable to find how to fix it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

To serialize an XML document with a document type declaration, use the `fn:serialize()` function with the `doctype-system` parameter:

```
xquery version "3.1";

fn:serialize(<root/>, map { "doctype-system": "validation.dtd" })
```

This produces the following string:

```
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "validation.dtd">
<root/>
```

For more on this technique, see the function documentation for `fn:serialize()` at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-serialize and description of the `doctype-system` and `doctype-public` parameters in the XSLT and XQuery Serialization 3.1 Specification at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#XML_DOCTYPE.

For processors that only support XPath 3.0 or that have not yet implemented the `map(*)` method of specifying serialization parameters, you can use this form:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

fn:serialize(
    <root/>, 
    <output:serialization-parameters>
        <output:doctype-system value="validation.dtd"/>
    </output:serialization-parameters>
)
```

Comment: Which XQuery processor and version are you using? Many processors implemented their own version before this facility was added to the standard.

Comment: I'm using the Saxon parser

Comment: Which version of Saxon?

Comment: For serializing with Saxon in versions that did not yet support XPath 3.0, see the `saxon:serialize()` function: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/serialize.html. But if you're using Saxon 7.1 or newer, `fn:serialize()` is supported. You may need an alternative form for specifying the serialization parameters. I'll amend the answer showing this alternate form.